# When I use 301 redirect, I get the wrong url address

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, routes

My redirect is as follows:

```
   Redirect 301 / http://testsite.com/en/
```

I get the following address: testsite.com/en/en/en/en/en/en/en/en
I worked in a .htaccess file. Where is my mistake?

Comment: you forgot the colon before the double slash

Comment: Thank you, but in my .htaccess file  everything was correctly written, but not working.

Comment: What does `curl http://testsite.com/en/` return? (Use curl, not a web browser -- you want to avoid multiple redirects being hidden)

Comment: Since `Redirect` is _prefix matching_, the above directive results in a redirect loop (`/en/en/en/en`... until the browser gives up).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `RedirectMatch` to target precise URL using regex:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/$ http://testsite.com/en/
```

Make sure to test this after clearing your browser cache.